# selecting multiple categories in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application i have a module called customer creation and the customers table looks like

```
create_table "customers", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB      DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "address"
t.string   "affiliate_id"
t.string   "category"
t.string   "domain"
t.string   "phone"
t.string   "contact"
t.string   "email",                           null: false
t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
t.text     "comments",          limit: 65535
 end
```

and the form for new customer looks like

```
  <%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
   <% if @customer.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>
    <%= "#{pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this customer from being saved:" %>
    </h2>
    <ul>
    <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>
        <%= msg %>
      </li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
     </div>
      <% end %>
     <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :name %>
     <%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control" %>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :address %>
      <%= f.text_field :address, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :affiliate_id %>
   <%= f.text_field :affiliate_id, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Category </label>
    <%= f.select  :category, [["Alexa Sills" ,"Alexa Sills" ],     ["Appliances","Appliances"],["Vehicles","Vehicles"],["Video Games","Video Games"],["Wine","Wine"],], {id: 'category', prompt: 'All Departments'},   class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :domain %>
   <%= f.text_field :domain, class:"form-control" %>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :phone %>
   <%= f.text_field :phone, class:"form-control" %>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :contact %>
     <%= f.text_field :contact, class:"form-control" %>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :email %>
     <%= f.text_field :email, class:"form-control" %>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label "Additional Details" %>
    <%= f.text_area :comments, rows: 10, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">

<% f.fields_for :additional_fields do | ing | %>
  <%= ing.text_field :key, :size => 50 %>
  <%= ing.text_field :value, :size => 50 %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
  <div class="actions">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
   <!--%= f.submit '+', :name => "add_additional_fields" %-->
    <span><%= f.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-success" %></span>

  </div>

   </div>
   </div>
   <% end %>
```

How can I select multiple categories  while creating a new customer, so that i can display the related products to that customer.
Please suggest the best way to do that.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to permit this array 
1) in your views with `:category[]` instead of only `:category`

2) in your controller's private method also add those brackets "[]" behind the category parameter.

And you would need multiple = true in your html form as mentionend by the other guy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **select2.js** which gives multiple option you can check it [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `multiple => true` in the category dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label> Category </label>
 <%= f.select  :category, [["Alexa Sills" ,"Alexa Sills" ],["Appliances","Appliances"],["Vehicles","Vehicles"],["Video Games","Video Games"],["Wine","Wine"],], {id: 'category', prompt: 'All Departments'},{ :multiple => true},   class:"form-control" %>
</div>
```